# cx_Freeze generated msi for wxpython script causes ImportError: DLL load failed

Tags: python, wxpython, cx-freeze

I have generated the msi for wxpython scripts but when I run the exe file I'm getting the following error but it is running on RAW Python Scripts

Error message:

> from ._core import * ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified procedure could not be found

[Image of the full error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/umOnB.png)

Configuration: python 2.7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After so many hours of debugging I found out that, While building the MSI file the **cx_freeze** is not completely copying the **wx**,**idna** and **pycparser** libraries.
So to solve resolve that issue, Once you install the MSI file copy those three libraries from Python Lib Folder ( **C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages** ) and replace it with the Same libraries in your MSI Installation lib folder.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at [this post](http://wxpython-users.1045709.n5.nabble.com/Phoenix-on-Windows-ImportError-DLL-load-failed-td5726752.html), your problem is probably caused by the DLLs `MSVCP140.dll` and `VCRUNTIME140.dll` missing in the directory of the executable.

In a first step, find these 2 DLLs on your system (usually under `C:\Windows\System32` or somewhere in your Python directory) and copy them manually into the installation directory after you have run the `msi` installer.

If this solves the problem, you can automatize this solution by adding something like the following entry to the `options` kwarg of the `setup` call in your `setup.py`script:

```
options = {'build_exe': {'include_files': ['path_to/VCRUNTIME140.dll', 'path_to/MSVCP140.dll']}}
```

where `path_to` is replaced by the correct path to the DLLs on your system (may also be different for both DLLs).